# Deploy multiple instances of the same application on JBoss

Tags: deployment, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb-3.0, seam

I want to deploy multiple instances of the same Seam/EJB3 application that differ only in their database settings on the same JBoss server instance. That way I want to provide different demo instances of this application.

Is this possible at all? And if it is what do I need to change in the configuration of JBoss and the application instances themselves (I could use ant to build different versions of the application with different configuration files if needed).

Answer (score 0):

Yes that should be possible. Just remember to also change the `application.xml` so that each instance gets its own name.

Comment: Also, not sure if duplicate loader-repository in jboss-app.xml will have any problems?

Comment: can you elaborate how, we can do that.